# GWT usage of AsyncCallback; code management

Tags: java, gwt, asynccallback

GWT newbie here and I'm trying to understand the philosophy of GWT when using RPC. So say I have `onModuleLoad()` and there's a login page (username & password). So when the user clicks submit it invokes `new ClickHandler()` and say that I need to do the followings:

1. Authenticate the user (pw & username are valid)
2. Log the entry
3. Add user to session

Questions:

1. Do I need to write for every item above `AsyncCallback`?
2. Does every action on the client side should have a `AsyncCallback` with `onFailure` and `onSuccess`? Isn't too much coding (comparing with struts?)

So at the moment my code looks like this, it has 2 AsyncCallback nested in the `onSuccess` which is a big problem because the execution of the SessionService comes AFTER I place a message on the screen for the end use.

```
            MongoDBServiceAsync mongoDBServiceAsync = GWT.create(MongoDBService.class);
            ServiceDefTarget serviceDef = (ServiceDefTarget) mongoDBServiceAsync;
            serviceDef.setServiceEntryPoint(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()+ "dbservice");

            try{

                mongoDBServiceAsync.isValidUser(user, new AsyncCallback<User>(){

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable caught)
                    {
                        //show error to user                    
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(User userDB)
                    {
                        SessionService.Util.getInstance().addUserToSession(userDB, new AsyncCallback<Void>(){  //yet another AsyncCallback

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Throwable caught)
                            {
                                //something went wrong 
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void result)
                            {
                                //add user to session 
                                // problem - this can be executed AFTER I wrote on screen: Hello USER_NAME 
                            }});
                    }        
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `asynccallback` is necessary for every GWT RPC call.That's we are able to manage the actions of user with according to server.

Coming to you actual problem, you need to have multiple RPC nested. Just revamp you `isValidUser` server side implementation such that it can also add the user to session.

```
User isValidUser(User user) {
//validate user with DB
//if valid, add to session
return user
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't 'validate user' AND 'adding user to session' is counter to decoupling? I mean, I don't want to encapsulate those 2 items together as they are different actions. So, am I left with nested onSuccess? Thanks Suresha!

Comment: RPC granularity should be rather coarse (if only for performance), then inside your RemoteServiceServlet you're free to decompose and dispatch to finer grain business services.

Comment: @adhg Why don't you simply create another RPC `authenticateUser` for login ?